# How to run script as a whole in remote computer from PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

Script is

```
Enable-PSRemoting -Force
$username = ComputerName
$password = Password | ConvertTo-SecureString -Force -AsPlainText
$cred = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential  $username, $password
$session = Enter-PSSession -ComputerName computername -Credential  $cred"

Set-Location -Path "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE"
.\Mstest.exe /testsettings:"D:\folder1\Local.testsettings" /TestContainer:"D:\folder1\Webtest\AssetUpload_WT.webtest"
```

When I run the first 5 lines in first run and the last 2 lines in second, It is working fine.

How to run whole script in PowerShell so that it should work?

Comment: You cannot run a script through PSRemoting when PSRemoting is not yet enabled.

Comment: Are you getting any error ? I can see the 6th line is for only setting the location. What is wrong in that ?

Comment: What do you mean by "first run" and "second run". What exactly do you run where? Have you tried `Invoke-Command` for running things on a remote host. Note that you need to enable PSRemoting on the *remote* host.

Comment: @RanadipDutta, I am getting error as "D:\folder1\Local.testsettings" not found.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers, Run the above code in 2 steps by seperating the code(1.run the fist 5 lines 2.run the last 2 lines),working fyn. But running the above code in single run,it was not working.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers,Thank you. I tried with Invoke-Command,it is working as expected.